# Cooling fan sudden alarming erratic behavior

Tags: hardware

Help needed understanding if this is an emergency or not...
Anyone familiar with raspberry pi 5V powered micro fans.

SKIP TO THE END for the tl:dr but here is a detailed description:

I have a tower of 4 raspberry pi's. 2 of them are Raspberry pi 3B+ and the other 2 are raspberry pi 4.

The tower came with cooling fans, one per pi. They are all installed the same way: by using 5V and ground pins to provide power to the fans, which are mounted over each pi in the structure, as per the instructions that came with the tower.

I have used this tower for almost 2 months, no problems.

### JUST NOW only ONE of the fans is exhibiting this UNSETTLING BEHAVIOR:

It comes to a stop (making a slight "revving" sound as it stops suddenly), then it starts running up to full speed again after a pause of around half a second. Then I hear it stop again. It performs this "revdown stop" more than 8 times in a row. It kinda sounds like a "braking " sound.

Then it will run normally for a few more seconds,

then it sounds like it is running slower than normal (and it certainly sounds like it is rotating slower than the other 3 fans), because it creates a steady "almost grinding" tone sound for a second or two.

Then it runs normally for a few more seconds.

Then it does the whole revdown stop sequence again...

It seems to randomly do a "revdown" stop sequence, and randomly spin slower, then spin fine.

### What I have done:

I checked the fan for dust or blockage, but there doesn't seem to be any.
The other fans work fine, all the connections are the same, and no connection is loose. I also checked the temperature of the pi in question via ssh and the temperature is not higher than usual (around 40).

The pi which THIS FAN IS ATTACHED TO is, RIGHT NOW AS IT IS CONTINUING TO BEHAVE AS DESCRIBED, performing a CPU intensive task (it is scraping large amounts of data). It has performed this task without any problems every night (for over a month) it has been in the tower with its fan working fine.

My theory: the pi is consuming a large amount of power for certain operations related to its scraping task and is cutting power to its 5V pins, which causes the fan to slow down in such a dramatic fashion whenever it cuts power.

My concern: that my pi will burst into flames, or short out, or otherwise break while I am not around because of this. Or the fan will die, and the pi will overheat, and the task it must do every day will not be done due to overheating and all that crap.

### TLDR

is it cause for alarm that a 5V powered micro fan randomly/intermittently and loudly slowdown before resuming normal behavior? What causes this behavior? Is it related to CPU power consumption or something? Must the fan be replaced or is this normal? What is the fix?

Thank you for your help in advance, this is occurring right now and I'm suppressing the urge to panic.

:)

edit: here is the tower
[https://www.amazon.com/iUniker-Raspberry-Cluster-Heatsink-4-Layers/dp/B07CTG5N3V/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=raspberry+pi+tower&qid=1576852227&s=electronics&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CTG5N3V)
I set mine up, it has worked fine for roughly 2 months. The fans that came with the tower get power from the pi each fan is attached to.

further edit:
ALSO I WAS INCORRECT IN SAYING GPIO PINS! It is actually powered by 5V pin. My apologies, I don't use those pins for anything else and I thought they were all collectively called GPIO pins, I realize now the distinction. I have corrected this in the post now.

yet another edit: as per goldilocks's generous considerations:
from what I can understand, it seems, when plugging an inductive load such as fan into the 5V pin, there is a (slight) risk that (if the fan stops) there will be a (excuse my layman's attempt to explain) reverse polarity thing that happens when the magnetic field generated by the fan motor goes back through the wire, which could arc across to the nearby pins and screw up the pi (over time?). Since this pi has been operating in this tower with a fan, the fan has accumulated a very very small amount of dust (which at some point might block it from spinning), but I figure if I put the whole tower in a box then no more dust should be able to get in in the future and this risk will be minimized. Or the fan could be powered from a source other than the 5V pin, which will require more effort to set up (albeit minimize the risk entirely). For now, I figure I'll go the 'enclose it within a box' route and check it for dust buildup regularly.

Comment: The GPIO can not provide enough power to run a fan.  Could you explain what you have really done and add some photos clearly showing the connections between the Pi(s) and fan(s).

Comment: I bought the tower from amazon, I included the link to the product page for reference. I've set mine up just fine, it has worked for around 2 months, the fans have enough power to spin quite nicely (very quiet). And it has worked very well for keeping the pi's from overheating. All I have done is check the fan for obstruction and then checked the temperature of the pi in question over ssh (it is not overheating).

Comment: You might try rearranging the fans to see if it is something physical, but I suspect you are right about it being a power issue.   Fans are inductive loads and running them right off the pi this way is not ideal.  It would be much better (and pretty simple to arrange) running them off their own DC supply.

Comment: Is it safe (enough) to (carefully) unplug something from the 5V without shutting down the pi? Alternatively put, can you freely plug and unplug things from the 5V pins while the pi is still running?

Comment: UPDATE: the pi has been running normally now for about 20 minutes...and then it did a weird revdown sound sequence again...and now it is running normally again...maybe this has been happening the entire time I've had the thing but I was always out of the room when it was happening...? In any case, it would still be nice to know WHY this happens at all (if anyone knows), and perhaps this will reassure anyone else with a similar situation. I still appreciate the consideration tho, joan and goldilocks! :)

Comment: Note that I was aware the fans were running off the 5V rail (and not actual GPIOs) when I wrote "this way is **not ideal**".  That the fan behaves that way (consider it in relation to *inductive load*) probably moves it into "just plain risky" territory.  Continue your inquires (you might be better off asking about small DC fans on our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)) but prioritize getting some other cooling system or, again, providing the fans with an independent power source.

Comment: You can't, you need an ammeter in line with the supply.  You should check the system logs for `Under-voltage detected!`.  WRT "Is it safe (enough) to (carefully) unplug something from the 5V without shutting down the pi?" -> In general yes (remove the 5V, then the ground), but that *inductive load* issue complicates it.  That said, if they were really prone to causing damage that way I think they would do it when normally powering off, so it should be fine (beware I'm not an electrician and have made some bad judgement calls in this area, lol).

Comment: killer info goldilocks! I'll try swapping out the fans and see if there's continued weirdness after this pi is done with its scrape (I've already screwed up the database it scrapes into once before in the past and I don't wanna risk anything while its performing any write operations to it and such...superstitious...). regarding checking the power, I made another post about that as I realized it was a bit off topic maybe. Right now the fan is a bit rattle-y, but the dramatic sounds have mostly subsided...i'll report back when it's done scraping...and thanks again for evryting!

Comment: I checked the system logs with ```journalctl -xe``` and didn't see an ```Under-voltage detected!```...

Comment: Seems like a classic fan bearing problem. Nothing to do with the Pi